# Pointer casting leads to crash in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, crash, virtual

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    virtual void print() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void print() {
        std::cout << "test\n";
    }
};

Base* getBase (Derived* d) {
    return (Base*) d;
}

int main()
{
    Derived* d;
    Base* b = getBase(d);
    b->print();

    return 0;
}
```

This code compiles (with g++) without any problem but after running, it crashes!
I tried different kinds of casting (like static_cast<>) but nothing worked.

What is the problem?

Comment: Although not the issue here do NOT use C-style casts in for C++ objects - there are corner cases where they dont work and give simply the wrong result. Use static_cast instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Derived* d;
```

That's a pointer, but you don't initialise it to point to a `Derived` object, so it has an invalid value. Using it gives undefined behaviour; most likely, a crash due to accessing an invalid address.

Try creating an object, then using a pointer to that:

```
Derived d;
Base * b = getBase(&d);
```

Note that the evil cast (or even a less evil C++ style cast) isn't necessary to convert to a base-class pointer; you could just do

```
Base * b = &d;
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not allocating the instance of the object, eg

```
Derived* d = new Derived();
```

So the variable `d` contains garbage data which can't be dereferenced.